# How to count the result after substraction in certain ranges

Tags: python

I have a script which is doing substraction for the values in file, And I need to count how many values were in `ranges` from `0-10, 10-100, 100-500, 500-1000, 1000-2000, 2000-10000`
My script is looking like this now:

```
with open("result.txt", "rt") as f_i, open("output.txt", "w") as f_o:
    count_0_10 = 0
    for line in f_i:
        orsDist, localDist = line.split(" - ")
        a = int(float(orsDist))
        b = int(float(localDist))
        c = a - b
        if 100 <= c < 500:
            count_0_10 += 1
    f_o.write(str(count_0_10) + '\n')
```

I've read some documentation about this, but i still can't understand how to do this.

Remove empty lines

```
with open('result.txt') as infile, open('result1.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if not line.strip(): continue  # skip the empty line
        outfile.write(line)  # non-empty line. Write it to output
```

Ranges counter short version

```
bounds = [10, 100, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000]
counts = defaultdict(int)

with open("result.txt", "rt") as f_i:
    for line in f_i:
        a, b = (int(float(token)) for token in line.split("-"))
        c = a-b
        if c < 0:
            continue
        for bound in bounds:
            if c < bound:
                counts[bound] += 1
                break

with open("result.txt", "w") as f_o:
    lower = 0
    for bound in bounds:
        f_o.write('in range {}-{} - {}\n'.format(lower, bound, counts[bound]))
        lower = bound
```

Comment: `if 0 <= c  < 10: count_0_10 += 1`, etc.

Comment: Alright, now i stuck in how to output this)

Comment: `print(count_0_10)`, etc.

Comment: if you mean write in file then you can open `output.txt` after `for`-loop and then write it. ie `f_o.write(str(count_0_10) + '\n')`, etc.

Comment: @furas check my edit, i've tried couple variants of your code, but I can't get it...

Comment: you are wrong. You have to use `if` inside `for`-loop and `write()` after `for`-loop when you have all counted. And don't foreget to create `count_0_10 = 0` before `for`-loop.

Comment: Okay now it works. Going to think how to make it write for many ranges in one time) Thank you

Comment: to write it in one line you can concatenate all in one string and then `write()` it. But to concatenate values you may need also few lines so it will not be shorter.

Comment: @furas I need to write it on separe lines like this
`in range 0-10 - <value>`
`in range 10-100 - <value>`
e.t.c

Comment: see my answer - I write every value in separated line because I add `'\n'`. You have to only add your text `in range ...`

Comment: see changes in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
count_0_10 = 0
count_10_100 = 0
count_100_500 = 0

with open("result.txt", "rt") as f_i:
    for line in f_i:
        orsDist, localDist = line.split(" - ")
        a = int(float(orsDist))
        b = int(float(localDist))
        c = a-b
        if 0 <= c < 10:
           count_0_10 += 1
        elif 10 <= c < 100:
           count_10_100 += 1
        elif 100 <= c < 500:
           count_100_500 += 1

with open("output.txt", "w") as f_o:           
    f_o.write('in range 0-10 - ' + str(count_0_10) + '\n')
    f_o.write('in range 10-100 - ' + str(count_10_100) + '\n')
    f_o.write('in range 100-500 - ' + str(count_100_500) + '\n')
```

If you use Python 3.6+ then you can format string using `f-string`

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as f_o:           
    f_o.write(f'in range 0-10 - {count_0_10}\n')
    f_o.write(f'in range 10-100 - {count_10_100}\n')
    f_o.write(f'in range 100-500 - {count_100_500}\n')
```

---

**EDIT:** I would use dictionary to keep ranges and counts.

As key will be tuple `(start,end)` and as value will be `count`

Currently dictionary should keep order of keys but to make sure I sort keys when I write it.

```
ranges = { # (start,end): count
    (0, 10): 0,
    (10, 100): 0,
    (100, 500): 0,
}

with open("result.txt", "r") as f_i:

    for line in f_i:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue

        orsDist, localDist = line.split(" - ")
        a = int(float(orsDist))
        b = int(float(localDist))
        c = a-b

        for (start,end) in ranges.keys():
            if start <= c < end:
                ranges[(start,end)] += 1
                break

with open("output.txt", "w") as f_o:
    for (start,end),count in sorted(ranges.items()):
        f_o.write(f'in range {start}-{end} - {count}\n')
```

I tested it using `io.StringIO` instead of input file, and `print()` instead of output file

```
import io

ranges = {
    (0, 10): 0,
    (10, 100): 0,
    (100, 500): 0,
}

data = '''4 - 1
100 - 1
500 - 1
100 - 10
10 - 2
'''

with io.StringIO(data) as f_i:

    for line in f_i:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue

        orsDist, localDist = line.split(" - ")
        a = int(float(orsDist))
        b = int(float(localDist))
        c = a-b

        for (start,end) in ranges.keys():
            if start <= c < end:
                ranges[(start,end)] += 1
                break

for (start,end),count in sorted(ranges.items()):
    print(f'in range {start}-{end} - {count}')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. Yeah i'm using 3.7.4 now, so it's cool for me

Comment: you can also write it as one string `f_o.write(f'in range 0-10 - {count_0_10}\nin range 10-100 - {count_10_100}\nin range 100-500 - {count_100_500}\n')` but it is less readable for people.

Comment: It's for statistics, I need to read it and put it in charts. I'm thinking now how to remove an empty line in my main script which is doing request

Comment: when you read lines from file then you get every line with `"\n"` at the end and you have to `strip()` it - `line = line.strip()`. After stripping you can also use `if line:` or `if not line:` to check if line is empty.

Comment: If you can, check it please - https://pastebin.com/U1gATRFD. `import os` is from my try to remove empty lines nevermind it

Comment: I did it by my own. Thank you at all for your help. check my edit to see how i did it

Comment: I saw your code on pastebin. You have to use `line = line.strip()` as first command in `for line in f_i` to remove `"\n"`. If you don't remove it then `split(",")` will keep `"\n"` in `file_dist` which you write to file - so finall you write  two `"\n"` - first which is in `file_dist` and second which you have in `"{from_api} - {from_file}\n"` - so finally you get empty line.

Comment: Now script is looking huge, because i implement in script from your answer with my additional ranges. It's working well and fast. I think it's all that i need, thank you)

Comment: I would use list or dict to keep ranges and counts and then I could use `for`-loop to check every range from list, and later to generate text `in range {a}-{b}` and to write counts from list. This way it code can be shorter and to add another range I would have to only add range to list.

Comment: Looks smart can you explain it to me in more details&

Comment: I tried to create list and use `for`-loop to check range, but it doesn't work, can you help pls?

Comment: I addes example with ranges in dictionary.